# How to resize my canvas to fit the same content no matter the size

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, scale

I am creating a game concept with this code: https://pastebin.com/pMNR1CfH. However, depending on the size of the window, more or less of the objects on screen will be shown. How can I resize it so the view remains the same?

I have these variables to try and scale the canvas, but I don't know where to place the canvas.scale function.

```
        var scalewidth = window.innerWidth / 1920;
        var scaleheight = window.innerHeight / 969;
```

thank you

Comment: So you want the image to deform (e.g. shrink by one axis) when the aspect ratio changes?

Comment: well if the window is shrunk significantly, you cant see any black space, and I dont want the the window size to effect how far you can see. Like I want an identical canvas when it is fullscreen and when its a super small window.

Comment: But, .... deform? Can you answer? Should a circle be allowed to become an elipse? Can you include images of how you imagine the transformation? Should it keep the original aspect-ratio? What if the original window is 1920x969 and user resizes to 1920x500. What should happen?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you want to:

- keep the aspect ratio of the graphics in tact (a circle should not be displayed as ellipse)
- completely visualise the area (0,0)-(1920,969) being used to make the drawing
- centre the graphics when there is spare room in one of the two dimensions of the view port.

Here is how you can do that:

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
window.addEventListener('resize', draw);

function draw() {
    // Get current 
    let viewSizes = [canvas.width = window.innerWidth, canvas.height = window.innerHeight];

    // Reset the canvas
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transformation
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ...viewSizes); // wipe

    // Determine scale factor
    let worldSizes = [1920, 969];
    let scales = worldSizes.map((worldSize, i) => viewSizes[i] / worldSize);
    let minScale = Math.min(...scales);

    // Determine shift in order to center the content
    let shift = scales.map((scale, i) => (viewSizes[i] - minScale * worldSizes[i]) / 2);
    ctx.setTransform(minScale, 0, 0, minScale, ...shift);

    // Draw the contents using world coordinates (0,0)-(1920,969): This is demo
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(960, 485, 484, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill(); 
    ctx.stroke(); 
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(10, 455, 1900, 60);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fill(); 
    ctx.stroke(); 
}

draw();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```